# Display one row from database and move to the next column

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

in my database table (id , book , cover , date , bookname .....) i used this method to display the row content of each column and it's working fine.

```
<?php    
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM books  ";
mysql_select_db('x');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM)) { ?>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="40%"><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
    <td width="40%"><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?
}  

mysql_free_result($retval);
mysql_close($conn);
```

But this time i want to display in each  one row (like:$row[0]) and 
in the next  also $row[0] but for the next column.example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
          <td width="40%"><?php echo $row[0];?></td>    //column1
          <td width="40%"><?php echo $row[0];?></td>    //column2
          <td width="20%"><?php echo $row[0];?></td>    //column3
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know if i should modify this code or use a new one .thanks for the help.

Comment: Store each columns data in its own array then output the arrays as you want. `$names[] = $row[0];`, `$emails[] = $row[1];` etc. then `foreach($names as $name){`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to show only one record then you can store the values in array first and later the display it on browser.

```
<?php

$email = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM)) { 
    $email[]=$row[0];
}
echo "<table>";
foreach ($email as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$value</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```